# How can I restrict access to a folder to only one user using SELinux in RedHat?

Tags: linux, redhat, selinux

I was thinking on creating a new type and assigning it to be accessible to only one role, then assign that role to only one user. Maybe I would need to create this new role. 
I'm not sure if changing a file's type would mess things up and then it wouldn't be able to execute. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to use SELinux for this? An easier way would be using an ACL no?

Comment: I've been asked specifically to use SELinux. So far I have been able to create a type and a role but I still don't know how to make the type accessible to this role only.